# How to crop an image in matlab using interactive tool?

Tags: matlab, crop

I want to crop out a window of size 250 X 250 pixels from an image at a specific place. How can I do that? I have seen `imtool` but I don't know how to control the size of cropping window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `imrect`, set the size and make it non-resizable, then `imcrop`, something like:

```
figure, imshow(I);
h = imrect(gca, [10 10 250 250]);
setResizable(h,0)
rect = wait(h);
% now move to appropriate position
% command line blocked until rectangle is double clicked
I2 = imcrop(I, rect)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways. For example you may have an image `im`, and use `imtool(im)` to find the coordinate `(x,y)` of the upper right corner of the window you want to crop down to. You can find this coordinate by holding you mouse curser over the pixel and looking in the parentheses in the lower left corner of the imtool-window.

Then you get the cropped image by `cropim = im(y+(0:249),x+(0:249));` or `cropim = im(y+(0:249),x+(0:249),:);` depending on how the image is stored.